# SAS: PROC UNIVARIATE: Output trimmed mean to dataset

Tags: sas

I'm doing the following the output the mean to a datset:

```
PROC UNIVARIATE DATA=have trimmed=0.05;
VAR age;
by sex;
output out=outputstats mean=theMean;
run;
proc print; run;
```

How can I output the trimmed mean? I can't find the keyword to request so I can select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ODS OUTPUT` to the rescue.  Use `ODS TRACE ON;` to find the name.

```
proc sort data=sashelp.class out=have;
by sex;

run;

ods trace on;
PROC UNIVARIATE DATA=have trimmed=0.05;
VAR age;
by sex;
ods output TrimmedMeans=trimmedMeans;
run;
ods trace off;
```

Comment: Brilliant. Can I restrict it to the TrimmedMeans column only?

Comment: You can do whatever you want in terms of dataset options on the output datset, so, `TrimmedMeans=trimmedMeans(keep=TrimmedMeans)`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can skip the ODS statements and use the `outtable=` option...

```
PROC UNIVARIATE DATA=have trimmed=0.05 OUTTABLE=trimmedMeans(keep= sex _MEAN_);
```