# Output Winsorized dataset

Tags: sas

A user here gave me the following code ([SAS: PROC UNIVARIATE: Output trimmed mean to dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007979/sas-proc-univariate-output-trimmed-mean-to-dataset)) to calculate and output a winsorized mean to a datset:

```
proc sort data=sashelp.class out=have;
by sex;
run;

ods trace on;
PROC UNIVARIATE DATA=have trimmed=0.05;
VAR age;
by sex;
ods output TrimmedMeans=trimmedMeans;
run;
ods trace off;
```

How can I output a new version of the sashelp.class dataset with ALL the observations for age winsorized, rather than calculating a winsorized mean `by sex`. I don't want to winsorize at the category level, as I will be censoring data that is an outlier in that category and not necessarily an outlier in the entire datset.

Comment: Please provide an example output dataset.  I don't completely understand the question; it sounds to me that you just need to remove the `by` statement but that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you add a variable with a constant value and group by it?
This should solve the grouping issue.

Comment: You can simply skip the BY statement, so I don't see why that would help.

Comment: Point taken, I misunderstood your comment. 'doesn't make sense' does not mean 'is not possible'.

Comment: Yeah, I should've probably said "is too simple and obvious that it's probably not what you are asking about".